# Change drive letter of disconnected (reserved) device?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager, drive-letter, external-drive

First off, I've done this before so I know it is possible. The problem is I just can't recall HOW I did it before.

Basically, I reinstalled Windows 10. Before doing so, it was working well and it was configured just how I liked it. All of my document folders (pictures, music, videos, and downloads) were all redirected to my network drive, which was assigned to drive letter 'F'. It wasn't always assigned to drive letter 'F', though.

At square one drive letter's E, F, G, and H are all reserved for USB drives. This is default when installing Windows 10 on this machine. Before I found a way to change the drive letter of these so I could use the drive letters I wanted (E and F, since they are the ones I'm used to using for my other hard drives). Now I can't think of how I did it.

So the question is, how can I change the drive letters of the unconnected devices which have reserved drive letters that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this as I did last time... I remembered exactly how I did it...

I could've gave just a few more minutes of thought and never have posted this question at all, but maybe it'll be helpful in the future anyways.

1. Run diskpart (Win+R, "diskpart", Enter).
2. List your volumes and reserved volumes by doing "list volume".
3. Select the volume you want to change by doing "select volume ###", where "###" is the volume number seen in step 2.
4. Assign a new letter by doing "assign LETTER=###", where "###" is the new letter.

In my case all of the volumes I wanted to change were all Type "Removable" and had a "No Media" Status with no other info, this indicates them all being reserved for USB.